# Duplicated button with links for ios, android or desktop only links to desktop

Tags: javascript

In wordpress you're allowed to provide a button with links for IOS, Android and desktop, depending from where you're accessing the website the button should send you to the correct URL.

I'd like to have a button with links to the playstore, appstore and download link for pc. The first code works fine, but when you've duplicated the block the second button only sends you to the desktop url.

The code below works fine when you've 1 button, but when you've duplicated the post the second button will only send you to the desktop url.

Button:

```
<div class="section-button <?php if( $section_left_or_right == "right" ) { echo "float-right"; } else { echo "float-left"; } ?>">
  <a id="section-button" href="<?php echo esc_url($link_url); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr($link_target); ?>">
    <?php echo esc_html($link_title); ?>
  </a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var operatingSystem, userAgentString = navigator.userAgent;
var link = $("#section-button");
if (userAgentString.indexOf("iPhone") > -1 || userAgentString.indexOf("iPod") > -1 || userAgentString.indexOf("iPad") > -1) {
    operatingSystem = "iOS";
    link.attr("href", "<?php echo $section_link_ios; ?>");
} else if (/Android/.test(userAgentString)) {
    operatingSystem = "Android";
    link.attr("href", "<?php echo $section_link_android; ?>");
}
```

I expect that both buttons should send you to the android url if you're accessing the site on a android device and so on for IOS and desktop.

In F12-console I can see that both buttons are registered as android but only the first will send you to the android url and the second only sends you to the desktop url.

Comment: For the buttons, use `class="section-button"` instead of `id`. Then use `var link = $(".section-button");` as the second line of that script. (An `id` is supposed to be unique; if you have multiple buttons you need to use a class or some other method instead)

Comment: 'code' <div class="section-button <?php if( $section_left_or_right == "right" ) { echo "float-right"; } else { echo "float-left"; } ?>"><a id="section-button" href="<?php echo esc_url($link_url); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr($link_target); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($link_title); ?></a></div> 'code'

Comment: This is the html code for the button see if it's any use to you

Comment: What do you mean? I already gave you the full solution. Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Where do you want me to put the class tag? in the div or a?

Comment: Wait, I see that the `div` already has that as class. In that case never mind about adding the class, just use `var link = $(".section-button a");`

Comment: Hey if you can answer via the answer option I can mark this question as solved